# How to retrieve data of relation table in Apiato?

Tags: php, laravel, repository-pattern, eager-loading, apiato

I am using apiato framework,i am developing one API which is responsible for retrieving the data from the database upto this part is working ,Now i want to resolve the `N+1 Query` problem  for that i am using eager loading concept and `andersao/l5-repository` it's dealing `with()  fn` .when ever i use l5-repository concept  i removed defaultIncludes Array from transformer it's not retrieving data with relations,can you please help me to fix this issue

**Normal URL  when ever defaultIncludes Array available :** `v1/users`
it's working fine it's retrieving data from DB(users & subscriptions details).

**when ever i use eagerLoading and l5-reposiry concept**  : `v1/users?with=subscription` it's not retrieving subscriptions (only Usres).

**GetAllUsersRequest.php**

```
  public function prepareForValidation()
    {
        request()->request->add(['with' => 'subscription']);
        request()->query->add(['with' => 'subscription']);
    }
```

**UsersTransformer.php**

```
public defaultIncludes=['subscription'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use eager loading concept in the database queries it's loading the relationships with less time .

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading